# Reading from text files within a sandboxed solution

Tags: sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, solution-package, office-365

So I have a set of plain text files included in some directories within sandboxed solution. I want to use these text files to programmatically insert data to SharePoint Online using an event receiver.

I'm just looking for a simple way to read these files within my solution, anyone know of one?

Comment: Where are the files located in the solution?

Comment: Well, are they are just within a package. But I can move them to anywhere else within the solution if it makes things easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on where you store the files, you may not have access to them. Sandbox solutions do not have access to the local file system (see more restrictions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615454.aspx#BKMK_LowPrivilegeToken). You would have to store the files in a library to gain access to them.